# All of my Vim text is underlined

Tags: options

I have configured Vim and then noticed that all of my text is underlined for some reason. I am running WSL with the Hyper terminal and I also configured Vim using the [Ultimate Vim Configuration](https://github.com/amix/vimrc). Is there a setting to turn off all of the underlined text? I've attached a photo that shows the issue. Thank you!

[image: underlined text in vim]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: What about other terminals? gVim? Have you tried other colorschemes?

Comment: That is the main reason why I think using this kind of "ultimate configuration" is a terrible way to get started: As soon as something weird like this start happening it will take you hours or days to troubleshoot because you don't fully grok everything in your configuration. You can start with [how to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) and edit your question with the progresses you make.

Comment: @statox It should be confirmed as answer.